# Calculate Signal to Noise ratio in python scipy version 1.1

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, signal-processing

I have looked around online and it seems that the **signaltonoise** ratio function inside the **scipy.stats** is deprecated and is not available in version 1.1. Is there any other equivalent method inside scipy package since I have not been able to find it online.

And if not scipy then is there any other library recommended for such calculations ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As indicated in [scipy issue #609 on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/609), the `signaltonoise` function

> *[...]* is not useful except for backwards compatibility. The reason is that there's a Matlab signal-to-noise function http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html which means something different. This is not good, because scipy clones the Matlab interface of other signal-related functions, and this incompatibility apparently has no offsetting benefit.

If you do need this function for backward compatibility, the short implementation can be found in the [history of scipy repository](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1864) as (reproduced here without the documentation comments, [license](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/license.html)):

```
def signaltonoise(a, axis=0, ddof=0):
    a = np.asanyarray(a)
    m = a.mean(axis)
    sd = a.std(axis=axis, ddof=ddof)
    return np.where(sd == 0, 0, m/sd)
```