# add Gaussian noise to the time series in a way that achieves the specified signal-to-noise ratio

Tags: python, bash, numpy, shell, gaussian

I want to add Gaussian noise to the time series(of shape rows*column) in a way that achieves the specified signal-to-noise ratio(snr). As far as i know it is required to change the value of sigma to achieve the proper snr. Thus, In order to measure the proper snr i tried to write a sample code after reading the tutorials in stack-overflow,however i stack at how to defined x and y variable here.I am using voltage data to achieve it.Can anybody suggest a proper solution for the same.Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io

mu=0.0   
sigma=0.5

inpdata=np.loadtxt("test_data")  #shape rows=400 and columns =8
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, [inpdata.shape[0],inpdata.shape[1]])
noisydata =  inpdata +  noise

x=
y=

measuredSNR = 10*np.log10(x/y)
print(measuredSNR)
```

Comment: have a look here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/14862 This seems also be interesting https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/14862 Hence, I would make a fft and check amplitude vs noise floor. You should take a window function, though. This means you need to know the spectral properties of that function, but for the standard ones they should be well documented.

Comment: Maybe also intersting https://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/appnotes/computation_of_effective_no_bits.pdf

Comment: can you please suggest some links based on python or shell ...i am not acquainted with matlab

Comment: This may help [Calculate Signal to Noise ratio in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413068/calculate-signal-to-noise-ratio-in-python-scipy-version-1-1)

Comment: @FBruzzesi I need snr value in some decibel but your links give snr of every elements